# Elasticsearch issue after run [ curl http://localhost:9200 ] curl: (52) Empty reply from server. guide me on this please

Tags: magento2.3

Can you please guide me on this issue please.
After install elasticsearch install successfully
But while try this url [ http://localhost:9200 ]
Geeting this issue after run [ curl http://localhost:9200 ]
Error: curl: (52) Empty reply from server

[image]

elasticsearch.yml

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
      #
      # NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
      #       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
      #       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
      #
      # The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
      # the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
      #
      # Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
      # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
      #
      # ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
      #
      # Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
      #
      #cluster.name: my-application
      #
      # ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
      #
      # Use a descriptive name for the node:
      #
      #node.name: node-1
      #
      # Add custom attributes to the node:
      #
      #node.attr.rack: r1
      #
      # ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
      #
      # Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
      #
      path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
      #
      # Path to log files:
      #
      path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
      #
      # ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
      #
      # Lock the memory on startup:
      #
      #bootstrap.memory_lock: true
      #
      # Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
      # on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
      # limit.
      #
      # Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
      #
      # ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
      #
      # By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
      # address here to expose this node on the network:
      #
      #network.host: 192.168.0.1
      #
      # By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
      # finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
      #
      #http.port: 9200
      #
      # For more information, consult the network module documentation.
      #
      # --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
      #
      # Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
      # The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
      #
      #discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
      #
      # Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
      #
      #cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
      #
      # For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
      #
      # ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
      #
      # Allow wildcard deletion of indices:
      #
      #action.destructive_requires_name: false

      #----------------------- BEGIN SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -----------------------
      #
      # The following settings, TLS certificates, and keys have been automatically      
      # generated to configure Elasticsearch security features on 16-04-2022 08:53:38
      #
      # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      # Enable security features
      xpack.security.enabled: true

      xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

      # Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
      xpack.security.http.ssl:
        enabled: true
        keystore.path: certs/http.p12

      # Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
      xpack.security.transport.ssl:
        enabled: true
        verification_mode: certificate
        keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
        truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
      # Create a new cluster with the current node only
      # Additional nodes can still join the cluster later
      cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["vivek-HP-Laptop-14-ck2xxx"]

      # Allow HTTP API connections from localhost and local networks
      # Connections are encrypted and require user authentication
      http.host: [_local_, _site_]

      # Allow other nodes to join the cluster from localhost and local networks
      # Connections are encrypted and mutually authenticated
      #transport.host: [_local_, _site_]

      #----------------------- END SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION ----------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open this file using command below command

```
sudo nano  /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

and replace this setting with false
# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

After above change restart elasticsearch and check.

**`Thanks.`**

Comment: Thank you so much it's helped me. great brother. :)

Comment: mm that sounds not good

Answer (score 0):

check version:  `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'`

check health:   `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty'`

EDIT: You can also check this article describing the reasons for this occurring > https://epictools.dev/how-to-fix-the-error-curl-52-empty-reply-from-server/

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help me one single bit. Both command geeting same error
[ curl: (52) Empty reply from server ]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, running elasticsearch 7 with docker I got a working response, but when I installed Elasticsearch 8 I got an empty answer.
Just change the curl request from
`curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'` to https with

```
curl --cacert /etc/elasticsearch/certs/http_ca.crt -u elastic https://localhost:9200
```

**You'll need the password for the elastic user that was generated during installation.**

check [elastic reference documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html#deb-check-running)